# How to add hidden product to magento shopping cart?

Tags: ajax, magento, magento-1.9

I have a page, where I need to add hidden product to the shopping cart after clicking on a button.
I do not want to show the product, just add it to the cart.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the products visibility to "Not visible individually" from admin and in your controller file add the product programatically like this:

```
<?php
$productId = '123'; 
$qty = '3';
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $qty));
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
?>
```

You can call this controller using ajax also.